# Routes in Node/Express and deployed Angular not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes

Routes on a deployed Angular app do not work when served by Node with Express. I know this has been asked before but there is something I am probably missing that is driving me crazy.

File structure in the "express" folder where Node runs is roughly the following:

```
express
├── controller.js
├── index.js
├── ngForm 
│   ...see below...
├── node_modules
│   ...
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── file.json
│   └── rubric.html
├── router.js
├── ssl
    ├── cert.pem
    └── key.pem
```

and the Angular project is in ngForm:

```
ngForm 
├── angular.json
├── dist
│  └── rubric
│       ├── assets
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── main.js
│       ├── main.js.map
│       ├── polyfills.js
│       ├── polyfills.js.map
│       ├── runtime.js
│       ├── runtime.js.map
│       ├── styles.js
│       ├── styles.js.map
│       ├── vendor.js
│       └── vendor.js.map
├── e2e
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
├── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

Some relevant Angular code:

app.module.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/rubric', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  {path: 'rubric', component: RubricComponent},
  {path: 'rubricbuilder', component: RubricbuilderComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
]
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
```

The relevant Node.js code:

server.js:

```
app.use(express.static("ngForm/dist/rubric"));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ngForm/dist/rubric/index.html'));
});
```

I did run ng build from the Angular project in ngForm, and the output is in ngForm/dist.

When running `ng serve` in the AngularProject I can navigate to 
https://localhost:4200/rubric and https://localhost:4200/rubricbuilder  .

From Node I can only get to https://localhost:8000/ which redirects/changes the url to https://localhost:8000/rubric , but I cannot launch https://localhost:8000/rubric itself or https://localhost:8000/rubricbuilder. By poking around with the angular routes and re-running the build, I can make express show rubricbuilder on the / route, which changes the url to https://localhost:8000/rubricbuilder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with angular but this question is related to [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Because you did not define `/rubric` router in express middleware so you might get an error like `404 NOT FOUND`.

When using SPA router in HTML5 history mode, you need extra configurations for your server,

for example, send your SPA at every route:

```
app.use(express.static("ngForm/dist/rubric"));
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ngForm/dist/rubric/index.html'));
});
```

This might not be the best practice for express, you can search for other solutions, for example like VueRouter suggest using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) with express.

Comment: that works! Now i realize that my .get was setting up routing only for / whereas your .sendFile serves index.html, which sounds like the right thing to do. Let me check if that's the best practice for Node/Express and I'll accept your answer

Comment: Actually the lines with app.use((req, res) => .. I believe are not necessary. That also forces routing to the index.html, which is bad if there are other routes such as backend API